# Selenium Python, Creating loops in find_element_by_xpath

Tags: python, selenium, datepicker

day = '27'
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//td[@class='day'][text()= day]").click()

This is showing error. I want to randomly select user define date, for automation purpose, but it is showing error.

Comment: Please add the minimal code example and error.

Comment: Add the `HTML` source for the elements and error that you are facing, this will help us to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the day as variable. Below is the code. I have metnioned in Java. You can use similar concept in Python

```
public WeblElement DayToBeClicked(String Day){
  WebElement DayToBeClicked= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[@class='day'][text()='"+day+"']"));
  return DayToBeClicked;
}

DayTobeClicked.click();
```